# Style of NSUserNotification

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, nsusernotification

A `NSUserNotification` only shows the action button if the user sets the style of the notifications for my app to "alerts" in the system preferences. Can I somehow set this style for my application as a default instead of relying on the user to manually select it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took me a while to track down how to accomplish this in my own app.
According to Apple's [info.plist keys reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW1):

> **NSUserNotificationAlertStyle** Specifies whether the notification style should be **banners**, **alerts**, or **none**. The default value is banners, which is the recommended style.

In your case you need to define the key **NSUserNotificationAlertStyle** in info.plist with the value **alert**.

Comment: I have opened up a question in the Apple Dev Forums about this. If you see this you might want to check it to see if anything gets figured out. https://devforums.apple.com/message/745079#745079

Comment: To summarize the thread at Apple Dev Forums: you need to **code-sign** your app, and set the style to `alert` in the info.plist.

Comment: @SmilinBrian But how would you test this feature while you are developing your app? We usually sign not before publishing in the app store.

Comment: @MikeLischke Since code-signing is required to make it work, it seems pretty obvious that you will have to code-sign in order to test it.

Comment: This is totally impractal. In an organization where signing is done by someone else (say by the build team) no developer can sign the app just for testing. Not well thought out, I'd say.

Comment: You can (and should) sign your app with your “Mac Developer” key for development and testing. In your target's build settings, set “Code Signing Identity” to Automatic/Mac Developer. When it's time to ship the app, the build team builds an archive and exports the app from the archive. When exporting, Xcode (or `xcodebuild`) can resign the app with a Mac App Store certificate or a Developer ID certificate.

Comment: how exactly do I need to sign the app? I've signed it with Developer ID certificate and it still doesn't set it to alert type automatically when I allow notifications in system banner. I also set NSUserNotificationAlertStyle to alert in plist and tried other fresh computers and deleting app from notifications settings on mine. nothing. either it is signing has no effect or something else :( please help